# Replacing .php ext with .html through .htaccess for root files only not subdirectoy files

Tags: php, regex, apache, .htaccess, redirect

How we can replace .php ext with .html through .htaccess for root files only not subdirectoy files.

Example : www.test.com/home.php should be change to www.test.com/home.html
but www.test.com/admin/home.php should remain same.

I simply tried as below:

```
RewriteEngine on  
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} (.*)\.php  
RewriteRule ^(.*)\.php $1.html [R=301,L]  

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} (.*)\.html  
RewriteRule ^(.*)\.html $1.php [L]
```

Please assist me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use code like this in root .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine on  
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} (.*)\.php  
RewriteRule ^([^/.]+)\.php $1.html [R=301,L]  

RewriteRule ^([^/.]+)\.html $1.php [L,NC]
```

`[^/.]+` regex will make sure to make it work in root path only.

Answer (score 0):

Change your .htaccess file to:

```
RewriteEngine on  
RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^([^/]*)\.php$ $1.html [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)\.html$ $1.php [L]
```

Then update all links to your root pages to link to `*.html`

Comment: What is the point of the final line? It seems to serve no good purpose.

Comment: It sends the request to the original php file when the path ends with .html

Comment: I see that, but I don't see where the OP asked for that. He seemed to want the reverse (.php to .html) only.

Comment: I understood he wants to change only the URLs from .php to .html, not the original files.

Comment: Oh, I didn't understand it that way. If that's the case, though, the last line should be an [AliasMatch](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_alias.html#alias) rather than a RewriteRule - the way you've written it results in a redirect loop. Problem is, AliasMatch can't occur in a .htaccess file, it has to be in the main .conf file.

Comment: Why? It should not result in a loop.

Comment: Well, it does, at least on my machine. Try it and see on yours. It's easy to see why - you've got .php redirecting to .html, and .html redirecting to .php, which redirects back to .html, which redirects back to .php, etc. Btw, I was wrong about AliasMatch - it doesn't avoid the loop either.